# connecting mysql database from other directory using cmd

Tags: mysql, cmd

Here I need to connect a database **(sample)** that resides somewhere in drive say
`E:\mysql_files\sample` 
When I try to copy the **sample** database to the **data** folder of Mysql, the don't list the database when I use `mysql> show databases;`
 I too searched for it. To make them list I need to copy ib* files to the same path. But I can't copy those files while **mysqld.exe** is running.
Also tried other ways like connecting from external computer `mysql -u root -p {password} -h {127.0.0.1} -D {database_name}` (with and without path). All shows database does not exist.
Can somebody help me through this...
Original databases created by Mysql are stored in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\`
And I need to connect to the database which is in `E:\mysql_files\sample`

Comment: Try this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-data-directories.html

Comment: No bro. Thats not working.